# Binary Merge sort & Natural Merge sort

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

I know that homework questions are not the most popular on here, but I am at a total loss. I am doing an assignment which requires us to make multiple sorting algorithms. One of them however, is driving me insane. I can find no examples of it online anywhere, and he did not go over it fully in class. We have to make a merge sort that looks like this:

```
void mergeSort(int * a, int s, bool n = false)
```

Where a is the array, s is the size of said array, and n is false for binary merge sort, and true for natural merge sort. The problem is, I cant find what natural merge sort and binary merge sort are. I just find mergesort. And all of them ask for far more variables.

I am simply asking if anyone knows where I can find a good explanation of those two different types of mergesort.

Comment: They are both mentioned on the wikipedia page on merge sort. Found with a web search for "binary natural merge sort".

Comment: Do you happen to know of anywhere I can find examples? I looked at the wiki, and it doesn't help me all that much unfortunately.

Comment: It's homework. You're supposed to figure out code from abstract descriptions, not copy examples.

Answer (score 2):

I'm no expert on the topic, but the wikipedia page seems to be a good starting point
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort

It contains a section on natural merge sort with an example.

About binary merge sort:

> A variant named binary merge sort uses a binary insertion sort to sort
>   groups of 32 elements, followed by a final sort using merge sort. It
>   combines the speed of insertion sort on small data sets with the speed
>   of merge sort on large data sets

And insertion sort may be read about here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort

which contains a selection on binary insertion sorting.

About the variables. The wikipedia example of 'bottom up merge sort' (of which natural merge sort is a variant) has this signature:

```
void BottomUpSort(A[], B[], n)
```

where A is the array to be sorted, n its length. B is a work array, and if a read the algoritm right it needs be of length n too. Anyway, it can be created in the beginning of the algoritm and deleted in the end.