# What type of merge sort is this?

Tags: c++, sorting, mergesort

This is for an assignment and this is the sort example provided in the book. Is this a binary merge sort or a natural merge sort?

```
 #include <iostream>

    #include "util.h"

    /** 
      Merges two adjacent ranges in a vector
     @param a the vector with the elements to merge
    @param from the start of the first range
   @param mid the end of the first range
   @param to the end of the second range
*/
void merge(vector<int>& a, int from, int mid, int to)
{  
   int n = to - from + 1; // Size of the range to be merged 
   // Merge both halves into a temporary vector b 
   vector<int> b(n);

   int i1 = from;
      // Next element to consider in the first half 
   int i2 = mid + 1;
      // Next element to consider in the second half 
   int j = 0; // Next open position in b 

   // As long as neither i1 nor i2 is past the end, move the smaller
   // element into b

   while (i1 <= mid && i2 <= to)
   {  
      if (a[i1] < a[i2])
      {  
         b[j] = a[i1];
         i1++;
      }
      else
      {  
         b[j] = a[i2];
         i2++;
      }
      j++;
   }

   // Note that only one of the two while loops below is executed

   // Copy any remaining entries of the first half
   while (i1 <= mid)
   {  
      b[j] = a[i1];
      i1++;
      j++;
   }
   // Copy any remaining entries of the second half
   while (i2 <= to)
   {  
      b[j] = a[i2];
      i2++;
      j++;
   }

   // Copy back from the temporary vector
   for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
      a[from + j] = b[j];
}

/**  
   Sorts the elements in a range of a vector.
   @param a the vector with the elements to sort
   @param from start of the range to sort
   @param to end of the range to sort
*/
void merge_sort(vector<int>& a, int from, int to)
{  
   if (from == to) return;
   int mid = (from + to) / 2;
   // Sort the first and the second half
   merge_sort(a, from, mid);
   merge_sort(a, mid + 1, to);
   merge(a, from, mid, to);
}
```

I know a natural merge sort uses recursion and that does appear to be the method used here. However, I am not sure. We have to use a natural merge sort and a binary merge sort and report the results and discuss the findings.

Comment: That looks pretty recursive to me.

Comment: This does use recursion. The ```merge_sort``` method calls itself, which is by definition recursive. This is the natural merge sort.

Comment: "Natural merge sort" and "binary merge sort" are going to be academic terms that mean exactly what your professor chooses them to mean.  As we are not your professor, nor can we read your professors mind, you won't get good help here.  Now "natural run merge sort" is something on wikipedia and may be what you think the professor called "natural merge sort", but again, not a mind reader.

Comment: Recommendation: Since this is clearly homework you would be better off formulating an argument one way or the other or the other other and asking if you have missed anything that proves you wrong. Homework is cool at Stack Overflow, bit it is handled differently. Expect more guidance than an outright answer.

Answer (score 2):

The sort in your post is a natural merge sort.  The binary merge sort works like a merge sort with the additional step of using a binary insertion sort before the merge sort.

This is done to combine the efficiency of insertion sort on small sets of data with the efficiency of merge sort on large sets of data.

Check out the 'Variants' section here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort#Variants

Here is a related SO question, as well: [Binary Merge sort & Natural Merge sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29460179/binary-merge-sort-natural-merge-sort#29460283)